# Easy way to Increment private variables?

Tags: java

I was wondering if there was an easier way to increment another class's private variables. Here is how I generally would go about it:

If I only need to do this rarely in my code:

```
pc.setActionsCurrent(pc.getActionsCurrent()-1);
```

If I need to do lots of incrementing, I would just make a special setter:

```
//In the PC class
public void spendAction(){
    this.actionsCurrent--;
}

//In the incrementing Class
pc.spendAction();
```

Is there a better way to go about this? If the variable were public

```
pc.actionsCurrent--;
```

would be enough, and I can't help but feel I'm over-complicating things.

Comment: Define a getter/setter for that private field.  This is the standard way to go about doing this.

Comment: Encapsulation. Your private variables should not be changed by another object.

Comment: Everywhere you said incrementing but your code says you are decrementing.

Comment: if your variable is public then what can be best then 
object.propertyName++; or object.propertyName--;

Comment: I felt the same way when I was beginning to program. There are too many codes to write just to decrease a variable by one. But I was just used to it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define an increment method. For generality you could supply the increment as a parameter, and it could be negative:

```
public void increment(int augend)
{
    this.actionsCurrent += augend;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No. The method abstraction is generally the way to go about it, you might also pass in the increment value (and you can leverage that in your implementation). Consider something like

```
private long increment = 1;
private long myVariable = 0;
public void setMyVariable(long myVariable) {
    this.myVariable = myVariable;
}
public void setIncrement(long increment) {
    this.increment = increment;
}
public long getMyVariable() {
    return this.myVariable;
}
public void addToMyVariable(long val) {
   this.myVariable += val;
}
public void incrementMyVariable() {
   addToMyVariable(increment);
}
```

The above would allow the increment value to vary (and this is generally called [*encapsulation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29)).

Comment: OP is asking easy way.

Comment: @PiyushMittal Pay a programmer?

Comment: i guess the snippet you have given is little bit complex. @Elliott

Comment: So pretty much my specialized setter example? All I was looking for is the simplest possible way to do ++ or -- on a private variable. But I'll keep your example in mind if I ever need more complex incrementation.

Comment: I can't see the point of having the increment as a member variable. It would be far simpler to supply it as a parameter. Otherwise it isn't so different from the original code, and has the same timing window problems.